# Constant size char array to a relative 64-bit integer

Tags: c, arrays, computer-science

First, the char array is greater than 8 bytes, so we can't use it directly as a 64-bit integer.

In this case "relative" is defined as:

```
x = char[16]
y = char[16]
r = x / y

ax = approx_int64(char[16])
ay = approx_int64(char[16])
ar = ax / ay

ar ~= r
```

With a char array greater than 8 bytes, how could I efficiently convert that array to a relatively sized 64-bit integer?

Comment: Would you like to explain yourself?

Comment: I don't believe it a matter of efficiency, really... You are breaking down information to bits, taking only the most significant from the char array at 1 byte (4 bits) per character then placing it in a 16 byte (64 bit) integer. The efficiency is solely dependent on getting the bits and transferring them between types.

Comment: Can you just briefly explain what you intend to do and explain your approch, the question is not clear

Comment: @Kozmik: Why do you assume a byte is 4bits? This most likley is not the case.

Comment: @alk I was apparently not thinking well when I wrote that. By definition 1 byte (8bits), 64 bit (8 bytes). My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by "relatively sized 64-bit integer".  However, I will assume you consider each char[] to represent some sort of ordered number.

If that is the case, the best way to approximate relative size is simply to take the 8 most significant bytes in that representation, and convert those to a 64-bit integer.